# how to use projection matrices in econometrics

Tags: econometrics, regression

We have the below expression:
$$
P_{M_{1}.X_{2}} \cdot y
$$
I guess its interpretation is that they are the **fitted values obtained from the regression of** $y$ **on residuals that are obtained from the regression** of $X_2$ on $X_1$.

But what do we really mean by this? what is the thing we do actually with that regressions?

and How we can show that
$$
P_x - P_1 = P_{M_{1}.X_{2}}
$$

Comment: What does $x$ denote in $P_x$? And what is $P_1$? Is your model linear? Please give more details...

Comment: $P_x$ vector of fitted values from the regression of $y = X_1 \cdot \beta_1   +X_2 \cdot \beta_2 + u$ and $P_1$ is the one for $y = X_1 \cdot \beta_1 + u_1$

Comment: @Tatanik501 Actually $P$ is the projection matrix which is a special case of a projection operator in the context of a finite dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the above comment pointed out, it is always good to provide exact definitions when asking a mathematical question.

But since your notation (or the notation in the book/lecture notes you are reading) is fairly standard, I'll fill in the definition from my interpretation and then give an answer.

In a generic multivariate regression $y = X \beta + e$, we use $P_X$ to denote the projection matrix $P_X := X (X'X) ^{-1} X'$ and use $M_X := I - P_X$ to denote the annihilator matrix.

If we partition the big $X$ matrix into two parts as in $X = (X_1, X_2)$ and partition the big $\beta$ vector into $\beta = (\beta_1', \beta_2')'$ in the compatible way, then we can write $y = X_1 \beta_1 + X_2 \beta_2 + e$.

**Theorem. The result we want to prove** is that the projection matrix onto $X$ can be broken into two (orthogonal) parts: the projection matrix onto $X_1$ and the projection matrix onto $\tilde{X_2}$, where $\tilde{X_2} := M_{X_1} X_2 = (I - P_{X_1}) X_2$ is the residual from the projection of ${X_2}$ onto ${X_1}$.

**Algebraically, what we want to show is $P_X = P_{X_1} + P_{\tilde{X_2}}$.**

Before we prove this, we note that this result is a type of the so-called **Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem** in econometrics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem).

**Proof.** Using $X = (X_1, X_2)$, we expand
$$
P_X = X (X'X) ^{-1} X' 
= (X_1, X_2) \left[\begin{pmatrix} X_1' \\ X_2' \end{pmatrix} (X_1, X_2)\right]^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} X_1' \\ X_2' \end{pmatrix}
= (X_1, X_2) \begin{pmatrix} X_1'X_1 & X_1'X_2 \\ X_2'X_1 & X_2'X_2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} X_1' \\ X_2' \end{pmatrix}.
$$

We use the simplified notation
$$
A := \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{pmatrix} 
:= \begin{pmatrix} X_1'X_1 & X_1'X_2 \\ X_2'X_1 & X_2'X_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and also use
$$
A^{-1} := \begin{pmatrix} A^{11} & A^{12} \\ A^{21} & A^{22} \end{pmatrix} 
$$
to denote the inverse of $A$.

Now, using bock matrix inverse formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix),   we can derive
$$
\begin{align}
A^{22} & = A_{22.1}^{-1} := (A_{22} - A_{21} A_{11}^{-1} A_{12})^{-1} \\
& =(X_2'X_2 - X_2'X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1'X_2)^{-1} \\
& =(X_2' M_{X_1} X_2)^{-1} \\
& =(\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1},\\
& \\
A^{21} & = - A^{22} A_{21} A_{11}^{-1} \\
& = - (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2'X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1},\\
& \\
A^{12} & = A^{21\prime}, \\
& \\
A^{11} & = A_{11}^{-1} + A_{11}^{-1} A_{12} A^{22} A_{21} A_{11}^{-1} \\
& = (X_1'X_1)^{-1} + (X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1'X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2'X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1}.
\end{align}
$$

With these formulas, we go back to $P_X$ to derive
$$
\begin{align}
P_X & = (X_1, X_2) \begin{pmatrix} X_1'X_1 & X_1'X_2 \\ X_2'X_1 & X_2'X_2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} X_1' \\ X_2' \end{pmatrix} \\
& = (X_1, X_2) A^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} X_1' \\ X_2' \end{pmatrix} \\
& = (X_1, X_2) \begin{pmatrix} A^{11} & A^{12} \\ A^{21} & A^{22} \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} X_1' \\ X_2' \end{pmatrix} \\
& = X_1 A^{11} X_1' + X_1 A^{12} X_2' + X_2 A^{21} X_1' + X_2 A^{22} X_2' \\
& = X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1' + X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1'X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2'X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1' \\
& - X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1'X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2' \\
& - X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2'X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1' \\
& + X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2' \\
& = P_{X_1} + P_{X_1} X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2' P_{X_1} \\
& - P_{X_1} X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2' - X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2' P_{X_1} + X_2 (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} X_2' \\
& = P_{X_1} + (X_2 - P_{X_1} X_2) (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} (X_2' - X_2' P_{X_1}) \\
& = P_{X_1} + \tilde{X_2} (\tilde{X_2}' \tilde{X_2})^{-1} \tilde{X_2}' \\
& = P_{X_1} + P_{\tilde{X_2}}. \\
\end{align}
$$
Q.E.D.

P.S. Let me know if there is any typo. This is a lot of typing. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer :) it really helps me to see full algebraical expression to understand what we really do. I tried to do something similar but I was lost. I appreciate your time.